# In objective C, loading a sound.wav from path not found

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, ios5

I saw a few code snippets such as this one

```
NSString *path = [NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tone" ofType:@"wav"];

SystemSoundID soundID;
CFURLRef soundFileURL = (__bridge CFURLRef) [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
OSStatus errorCode = AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)soundFileURL, &soundID);
//play the file

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
```

So I enter this code in my program but when I debug, I see that there is an error 1500 which means I was unable to find the sound in question. I have however included the sound in the supporting files in the project. The sound file is also very small, 4kB

I also have images in png format which I include in the supporting files and they seem to load correctly regardless of actual location. SO why is this different?

Thanks

Comment: You might consider converting the .wav to a .caf. Saves you some space and also I'd recommend using the `AVFoundation` framework instead of `AudioToolbox`

Comment: I have it down at the bottom, but here it is.
Actually, it seems removing the sound file and adding it again, (possibly with the option of "copy file to project folder") does the trick. Not sure what was wrong in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it seems removing the sound file and adding it again, (possibly with the option of "copy file to project folder") does the trick. Not sure what was wrong in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURL *aFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"buzz" ofType:@"wav"] isDirectory:NO];
SystemSoundID aSoundID;
OSStatus error = AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)aFileURL, &aSoundID);

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(aSoundID);

AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(aSoundID);
```

Comment: Interesting about the CFURLRef, my compiler complains that I need the __bridge. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *clapPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Clapping Crowd Studio"  ofType:@"caf"];
CFURLRef clapURL = (CFURLRef ) [NSURL fileURLWithPath:clapPath];
SystemSoundID clappingFileID;   
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID (clapURL, &clappingFileID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (clappingFileID);
```

I use this code try it, may be useful for you

Comment: thanks. Additionally, the first time the sound plays seems to freeze up the interface. do you know why that is?